# include в c++

Tags: include, c++

Привет всем. Есть заголовок test.hpp и исполняемый main.cpp. 
В test.hpp

```
#include <string> 
/* my code */
```

В main.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include test.hpp 
/* my code */
```

Теперь вопрос: после препроцессирования класс string в код вставится 2 раза или 1?
Думал включение string из test.hpp убрать, но не компилируется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрим файл string.
Видим что-нибудь типа (у меня gcc/g++, для других компиляторов текст будет несколько иной):

```
ifndef _GLIBCXX_STRING
#define _GLIBCXX_STRING 1
...
#endif /* _GLIBCXX_STRING */
```

Т.е. при втором включении string символ `_GLIBCXX_STRING` уже определён и хедер-файл не включается, так же, как и при третьем, четвёртом. Насчёт пятого я, честно говоря, не уверен :)